# Как удерживать фокус в приложении WindowsForms на одном элементе?

Tags: c#, winforms, button

Есть форма с кнопками (калькулятор). По умолчанию фокус стоит на одной из кнопок (насколько я знаю, изменить фокус по умолчанию можно с помощью tabIndex). Как запретить другим кнопкам получать фокус (фокус должен всегда оставаться на одной кнопке)?

Чтобы было понятнее: кнопка с фокусом по умолчанию - "=" (т.к. калькулятор), и при нажатии Enter нажмется эта кнопка, т.к. она в фокусе (а ещё потому что `Form.AcceptButton` - тоже кнопка "=". Но при нажатии на другую кнопку (например "7") фокус переведется на "7" и, когда в фокусе "7", при нажатии Enter, нажмется "7", а `Form.AcceptButton` будет игнорироваться).

Да, я понимаю, что можно при нажатии на любую другую кнопку сразу переводить фокус обратно, но можно ли в принципе запретить определенным кнопкам получать фокус?

Я пробовал выставлять `Form.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false)` и `ActiveControl = null`, но, судя по всему, это не то, что я ищу. Также я пробовал выставлять `Button.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false)` для каждой кнопки при создании формы, но на это я получал ошибку `Cannot access protected method 'SetStyle' here`.

И ещё я надеюсь, что это можно провернуть со стандартными кнопками и не придется создавать класс своей, потому что интерфейс я делаю в конструкторе.

На скриншоте пример фокуса, о котором я говорил - при нажатии на "1" фокус остается на "1", а мне нужно, чтобы фокус всегда был на "=" (или нигде, потому что в таком случае мне должно хватить `Form.AcceptButton`, но, насколько я знаю, фокус всегда должен где-то быть и это невозможно).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У всех кнопок кроме `=` выставить `TabStop=false`

Comment: @Bulson так они не получают фокус только если перещелкивать их Tab'ом. Если нажимать мышкой, то фокус они получают

Comment: можно поставить в событии Click передачу фокуса нужной кнопке, у вас же в любом случае это событие как-то обрабатывается. Просто запретить нельзя, это нативный низкоуровневый механизм за пределами кода .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ProcessDialogKey](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.processdialogkey?view=netframework-4.7.2)

override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData) - 
позволяет обработать нажатие таких клавиш как Enter, стрелки влево/вправо, табуляция и прочие, поэтому логика фокусировки на элементах в окне приложения может быть переопределена.

Answer (score 0):

[msdn Form.KeyPreview](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview?view=netcore-3.1https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview?view=netcore-3.1)

`Form.KeyPreview` Свойство 
дает возможность обрабатывать нажатия клавиш KeyDown

Comment: Не понимаю, что, собственно, должно было измениться, но ничего не изменилось - при нажатии на любую кнопку, фокус получает нажатая кнопка (и при KeyPreview = true, и при KeyPriview = false)

Comment: Суть не в том чтобы удерживать фокус на элементе управления, я а в том чтобы обработать событие on enter в форме неважно на каком элементе управления будет focus, выполнить бизнес логику и пробросить события либо дальше либо прервать. Я так понимаю речь идёт о калькуляторе где онEnter необходимо получить расчётное значение..

Comment: попробовал реализовать, в результате система не ловит именно Enter 
поймать событие можно просто переопределив  в форме метод  protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)

Comment: и кстати через 
        protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData) {
            return false;} решается и первоначальный вопрос - запрет перемещения фокуса

Comment: Не знаю почему, но Enter перестал работать) Соответственно, если нажать Enter, нажатие на кнопку "=" не вызывается. Но вообще это почти то же самое, что и отсутствие фокуса, что я изначально и искал. В любом случае, будет интересно послушать предположения, почему Enter перестал работать (если, конечно, это не то, что я и написал, переопределив функцию)

Comment: override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData) { return false;}
в этом случае все игнорируется, нужно добавить условие проверки keyData и возвращать true на Enter

Comment: Всё понял, спасибо)

Comment: Напишите ещё один ответ с override bool ProcessDialogKeys чтобы я отметил его решением